# When a vested transfer is sent to an account with vested and staked funds, the rewards become transferable. Is this expected?

Tags: staking, vesting-balance

Here is the scenario:

You get X DOT in vested transfer (with schedule A) and you stake them and compound the rewards (transferable = 0). After some time, you have X + Y staked and you get another Z DOT in vested transfer (with schedule B), where Z > X + Y. What you would expect to happen is:

- Total locked = Z + X + Y (i.e. the whole balance and transferable is still zero)
- 3 locks: X with vesting schedule A, Z with vesting schedule B, and X + Y for staking

However, what happens is:

- Total locked = Z + X
- Transferable = Y
- 3 locks as above

So, the user basically gets a "free" unstake of their staking rewards thus far (Y). As far as I can tell there's no security risk, since the total staked amount is still `X + Y` and the user can be slashed for that amount. In the case of a 100% slash, the excess will effectively be "taken" from Z, and they'll end up with vested balance of `Z - X - Y`, as they should.

However, is this the expected behavior? Because it was unexpected for me.

Example:

- Original vesting/staking: X = 1000
- Compounded rewards: Y = 100
- Second vesting: Z = 2000
- Vesting lock = Total lock: Z + X = 3000
- Staking lock: X + Y = 1100
- Total balance: Z + X + Y = 3100
- Transferable: Y = 100

Comment: in the description of the actual behaviour, you said that Y amount is transferable but at the same time it is locked (X + Y for staking, as in the expected behaviour). Is this what you tried to say? Also, quickly checking on mainnet I could see the expected behaviour in accounts with staking + vesting but not the second scenario you reported here.

Comment: Yes. The lock for staking is X + Y (the original amount plus the rewards). The total lock is the sum of the two vesting amounts: Z + X. So, the remaining (Y), since it's "beyond" the total lock is "translated" to transferable. I'll add an example in the question.